# Positive definite matrix proof - why $z^TUDU^Tz \underset {2} = \sum{d_i[U^Tz]^2_i}$ holds

Tags: linear-algebra

I am studying optimization theory from a german hardcover second hand book I bought lately.

It define:

> A symmetric matrix $X$ is positive definite if $z^TXz > 0$ for all $z
> > \neq 0 $.

And then cliams:

> $X$ is a positive definite matrix iff it is diagonalizable and its
>   eigenvalues are positive, proof:
>
> $$u^T_jUDU^Tu_j = d_j > 0$$
>
> and on the other hand:
>
> $$z^TXz \underset {1} = z^TUDU^Tz \underset {2} = \sum{d_i[U^Tz]^2_i} \underset{3} \ge 0 $$

I don't understand the other hand section. Why does $2$ hold? $1$ and $3$ are obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z^{T}U = [a_{1},a_{2}, \dots, a_{n}]$ then $U^{T}z = [a_{1},a_{2}, \dots, a_{n}]^{T}$.

$$z^{T}UDU^{T}z = [a_{1},a_{2}\dots,a_{n}]D[a_{1},a_{2}, \dots, a_{n}]^{T} = [a_1d_1, a_2d_2,\dots a_nd_n] [a_1,a_2,\dots a_n]^{T} = a_1^{2}d_1 + a_{2}^{2}d_{2} +\dots a_n^{2}d_n.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix:

$$D =\begin{matrix}
\lambda_{1} &  0  & \ldots & 0\\
0  &  \lambda_{2} & \ldots &0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0  &   0       &\ldots & \lambda_{n}
\end{matrix}$$

For any vector $v \in \mathbb{R^n} $ the relation: $ v^TDv = \sum_i {\lambda_iv_i^2}$ holds.